# Фильтр для сообщений с реплаем на бота aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, filter

Есть такой кусочек кода

```
ANSWER_PHRASE = [
    '',
    'Я просто делаю свою работу.',
    'Отвалите от меня, я занят.',
    '‍♂️',
    '',
    '',
]


@dp.message_handler(filters.IsReplyFilter())
async def joke_answer(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(text=random.choice(ANSWER_PHRASE))
```

Бот работает в группе телеграм.
Проблема заключается в том, что бот реагирует на все отвеченные сообщения, даже если ответили не на сообщение бота, хэндлер срабатывает.
Как сделать так чтобы это работало только если отвечают сообщение бота?

Comment: Покажите хоть этот `filters.IsReplyFilter()`

Comment: Судя по документации Aiogram выглядит он так


```
class IsReplyFilter(BoundFilter):
 
    key = 'is_reply'

    def __init__(self, is_reply):
        self.is_reply = is_reply

    async def check(self, msg: Message):
        if msg.reply_to_message and self.is_reply:
            return {'reply': msg.reply_to_message}
        elif not msg.reply_to_message and not self.is_reply:
            return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот фильтр который тебе нужен.

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import BoundFilter

class ReplyFilterBot(BoundFilter):
    async def check(self, msg: types.Message):
        try:
            if msg.reply_to_message.from_user.id == bot.id:
                return True
        except Exception:
            pass

@dp.message_handler(ReplyFilterBot())
async def joke_answer(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(text=random.choice(ANSWER_PHRASE))
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо.